# UITableView prepareForSegue not pushing to UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

I'm trying to push from `WebListViewController` to `WebPageViewController`, so when a cell is pressed it will push to a `UIWebView` to show the web article associated with it.  But I just can't get it working-

**WebListViewController.m**

```
#import "WebListViewController.h"
#import "Feed.h"

@interface WebListViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *headlinesArray;
@end

@implementation WebListViewController
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize headlinesArray;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Feed *feedLocal = [headlinesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *headlineText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.headline];
    cell.textLabel.text = headlineText;

    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"webpage"]) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    WebPageViewController *wpvc = (WebPageViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
    wpvc.buttonNumber = _buttonNumber;
    Feed *feedLocal = [headlinesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *stringWeb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.links.web.href];
    wpvc.stringWeb = stringWeb;
}
```

}

**WebPageViewController.h**

```
@interface WebPageViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) int buttonNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringWeb;
@end
```

**WebPageViewController.m**

```
#import "WebPageViewController.h"
#import "Feed.h"

@interface WebPageViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *headlinesArray;
@end
@implementation WebPageViewController
@synthesize stringWeb;
@synthesize headlinesArray;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringWeb];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.webView stopLoading];
}
```

**JSON response**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2013-05-04T16:38:48Z",
    "feed": [{
        "headline": "Text of headline",
        "links": {
            "web": {
                "href": "http://website.com/article"
            },
```

I just added the `<UIWebViewDelegate>` part today because I thought maybe thats what was happening, but it still wasn't working.  I know `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is correct because I see all of the correct data for it in the console.  When I Run the program it seems to never even get to the `WebPageViewController`, the cell selected stays highlighted.  I can't figure out what the problem is, if its `prepareForSegue` or needing to add `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or something different.

(I'm pulling JSON data from an API.)

Any advice would be super helpful, and I'll add any code needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing standardCell is a cell you have defined as a prototype cell in your storyboard? If so, make sure that you right click that cell and drag the "selection"-property to the view controller you want the cell to push onto the navigation controller.

[image: How to create a segue connection to another view controller]

Also, make sure the first view is embedded in a navigation controller. If it's not, select it in the storyboard, and go to the Editor-menu, select "Embed In", and then "Navigation Controller".

[image: How to embed a view in a navigation controller]

Comment: thanks for the response!  Yup, standardCell is a cell I defined as prototype in my storyboard.  Does this process your suggesting work even though I'm pushing from TableView -> WebView (your image is TableView -> TableView)?

Comment: Yes, it works the same for all view controllers, regardless of type.